# Track location when app is in the background in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

In my React Native app, I'm using [react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service) to track location changes. In iOS, the background location tracking works perfectly just by following [these](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service/blob/master/docs/setup.md#3-update-infoplist) instructions. The problem arises in Android which causes the tracking to stop or work randomly when the app goes into background.

***Let me emphasize that I don't want the location to be tracked when the app is fully closed. I ONLY want the tracking to work when the app is in the foreground (active) and background states.***

I've followed the instructions given in the package's own [example](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service/blob/master/example/src/App.tsx) project to configure and start the tracking service and just like them I use [react-native-foreground-service](https://github.com/voximplant/react-native-foreground-service).

This is the function responsible for tracking the user location with the `watchPosition` method of `Geolocation`:

```
// Track location updates
export const getLocationUpdates = async (watchId, dispatch) => {
  // Check if app has permissed
  const hasPermission = await hasLocationPermission();

  // Show no location modal and return if it hasn't
  if (!hasPermission) {
    dispatch(setAvailability(false));
    return;
  }

  // Start the location foreground service if platform is Android
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    await startForegroundService();
  }

  // Track and update the location refernce value without re-rendering
  watchId.current = Geolocation.watchPosition(
    position => {
      // Hide no location modal
      dispatch(setAvailability(true));

      // Set coordinates
      dispatch(
        setCoordinates({
          latitude: position?.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position?.coords.longitude,
          heading: position?.coords?.heading,
        }),
      );
    },
    error => {
      // Show no location modal
      dispatch(setAvailability(false));
    },
    {
      accuracy: {
        android: 'high',
        ios: 'best',
      },
      distanceFilter: 100,
      interval: 5000,
      fastestInterval: 2000,
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      forceRequestLocation: true,
      showLocationDialog: true,
    },
  );
};
```

And this is how the foreground service of `react-native-foreground-service` is initialized:

```
// Start the foreground service and display a notification with the defined configuration
export const startForegroundService = async () => {
  // Create a notification channel for the foreground service
  // For Android 8+ the notification channel should be created before starting the foreground service
  if (Platform.Version >= 26) {
    await VIForegroundService.getInstance().createNotificationChannel({
      id: 'locationChannel',
      name: 'Location Tracking Channel',
      description: 'Tracks location of user',
      enableVibration: false,
    });
  }
        
  // Start service
  return VIForegroundService.getInstance().startService({
    channelId: 'locationChannel',
    id: 420,
    title: 'Sample',
    text: 'Tracking location updates',
    icon: 'ic_launcher',
  });
};
```

And this is how it's supposed to stop:

```
// Stop the foreground service
export const stopLocationUpdates = watchId => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    VIForegroundService.getInstance()
      .stopService()
      .catch(err => {
        Toast.show({
          type: 'error',
          text1: err,
        });
      });
  }

  // Stop watching for location updates
  if (watchId.current !== null) {
    Geolocation.clearWatch(watchId.current);
    watchId.current = null;
  }
};
```

The way I start the tracking is just when the Map screen mounts:

```
const watchId = useRef(null); // Location tracking reference value
const dispatch = useDispatch();

// Start the location foreground service and track user location upon screen mount
useMemo(() => {
  getLocationUpdates(watchId, dispatch);
    
  // Stop the service upon unmount
  return () => stopLocationUpdates(watchId);
}, []);
```

I still haven't found a way to keep tracking the location when the app goes into background and have become frustrated with `react-native-foreground-service` since its service won't stop even after the app is fully closed (The problem is that the `cleanup function` of `useMemo` never gets called upon closing the app).

I have heard about [react-native-background-geolocation](https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation) (The free one) but don't know if it will still keep tracking after closing the app (A feature I DON'T want) and am trying my best not to use two different packages to handle the location service (`react-native-background-geolocation` and `react-native-geolocation-service`).

Another option would be [Headless JS](https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android) but even with that I'm not quite sure if it would stop tracking after the app is closed.

I welcome and appreciate any help that might guide me to a solution for this frustrating issue.

Comment: See the checklist in [Android Developers - Access location in the background](https://developer.android.com/training/location/background).  Device battery usage is a concern.

Comment: @Yogi Thanks a lot for the useful link. After adding the foreground service type of location as `android:foregroundServiceType="location"` as an element of `react-native-foreground-service` in `AndroidManifest`, it is now working on Android +10.